# Unauthorized Response from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Our client is using for Azure DevOps for code repository.  I've been able to connect and pull/push code for a year without issue.

I started on a new project for this client that uses the ADO Artifacts for a NuGet store.  My windows login for this project is different than my ADO account so when I build the solution in VisualStudio I get asked for credentials for the NuGet store.  I enter my credentials and it immediately asks me again for creds. It does this 4 or 5 times then finally fails.

Minutes to hours later, I can no longer pull/push code from the Git repos.  I've tried switching to a PAT but same result.  I can get into ADO through a browser and see the repositories.  I'm an org admin but can't see users and permissions during this time.  If I wait a few hours, it will start working again.  I verified my user is NOT locked in AzureAD.  I get denied on all devices (on and off client network).

I think I've fixed the issue of the NuGet authentication but does anyone know if there's a "lock out" feature in ADO that I'm missing?  If so, is there a way to "unlock" the user when this happens.

The error I get back in Git seems to be a standard failed authentication:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://****.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/projectname/_git/repo-name/'
```

Comment: `I'm an org admin but can't see users and permissions during this time.`  Press F12, if there is any prompt or error message?

Comment: I did notice one of the AJAX calls was giving a 401.  Things are working at the moment so I can't replicate and send which API it was.